# $variable = get_post_meta not working as expected

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

This is my first post on stackoverflow, as I am quite new to PHP. I am learning the language to help me customize my online portfolio in Wordpress, and I usually manage to make the changes I need - but not this time, apparently.

I am trying to use *get_post_meta* to read a meta tag in my portfolio pages, and avoid displaying the page thumbnail. This is the code I am using:

```
<?php  $disable_thumb = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'minimal_portfolio_page_thumb', true );
    if( $disable_thumb !== 'on' ): ?>

        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
            <div class="post-thumbnail">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                </a>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Using a meta tag management plugin, I added the following tag to all my "portfolio"-type pages:

```
<meta name="minimal_portfolio_page_thumb" content="on">
```

I am currently checking if this works in this page of my web: [egozalor.com/portfolio/hansel-gretel/](https://egozalor.com/portfolio/hansel-gretel/)

Long story short, the trick does not work as expected. I guess there is something I am doing wrong or not realizing, due to my little knowledge of PHP. Any indications, tips or recommendations are very welcome!

Also please let me know if further or more specific information is necessary to assess my issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function [`get_post_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) has nothing to do with the `<meta>` elements of your site. With this function you can only get metadata of the post itself. You can set the metadata on each post at the end (custom fields) as key / value pairs.

These custom fields are not visible on the site itself. You can create a custom field on every post with key `minimal_portfolio_page_thumb` and value `on` (or another value like 0/1).

---

Looks like the custom fields are disabled by default on WordPress. But you can enable the custom fields without an additional plugin. On the top right of your post you can find three dots to open a menu. At the end of the menu there is the entry "Options". On the options you can enable the custom fields.

You can enable the custom fields for posts and pages.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian! That makes sense. I was able to find the (custom fields) box at the end of my pages and blog posts, but that section is not available in my portfolio pages editor. I guess that's because the portfolio functionality is added by a third-party plugin - that's why I thought adding meta tags in the head could be a solution. Is there any other workaround to add a custom field to my "portfolio" pages?

Comment: Done! Managed to add the custom field using a different plugin: "Advanced Custom Fields." Thanks again for the tip!

Comment: @EsaúGozalo - see my update. You don't need a plugin for the custom fields.